# how to display a pdf file in Web view without storing it in SDCard

Tags: android

I am realizing an android project I am blocked that one I wanted to show a pdf in webview .the pdf file is accessible via an URL in localhost. 
when  I use this code,                         `webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+pdfurl);`

it shows : 
                                                                               "Sorry, we were unable to find the document at the original source. Verify that the document still exists.You can also try to download the original document by clicking here."

Help me to solve this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is located in your local server.It cant accessed from outside your network.Upload your pdf file to any website like [this](http://www.4shared.com/) or [this](https://www.dropbox.com/).And get the public url from there.Then try to access that url from your application.

Comment: I have to download files in dropbox, but it is impossible to reach  file. The same error displays on the emulator. Besides, every file have an  address in dropbox .so I cannot reach it dynamically.
The URL is in fact under this format: mWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/16.pdf?w=DEZ.....

Comment: did you upload your file in public folder? Then only you can access it from outside

Comment: Check this link, https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Public/1.pdf?w=AADaRstBRJmiqm0tcp_-DAzJiz_fZyzM6x5iza5hvafNHw   Its my pdf file I am currently using in my app.Try to view this file from your app.

Comment: your link works Perfectly. But when I used my link  "mWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=https://www.dropbox.com/s/ptwuxg15q3chr1s/30.pdf")"; In webView it shows me a code an not a view.What could be the problem???Is that a problem of wrong URL??

Comment: how did you get the url from dropbox? first u need to put the file inside your public folder and get the link by right clicking it and selecting "get public link"

Comment: The new accounts created after October 4th, 2012 do not propose any more the Public file.you can try to open by yourself this public file https://www.dropbox.com/sh/d15vvo4h7h88xx2/aLdsKAd0qZ.  The main problem that it displays code HTML of page and not a view at emulator'webview

Answer (score 0):

You can use the google's document viewer service for viewing the pdf,ppt contents in the webview if your document resource is on online.
create following HTML string like :
`String googleDocUrl ="<iframe src='http://docs.google.com/gview?url="
                    + YOUR_ONLINE_PDF_DOC_URL
                    + "&embedded=true' width='100%' height='100%'style='border: none;'></iframe>";`

call webviews loadData() method :

```
 mWebView.loadData(googleDocUrl ,"text/html","UTF-8");
```

Hope this might help you :)